# how do we call a javascript function after executing controller method

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a Vf page with save button. i am calling a controller method in the VF page. I would like to close the VF page once the save method is executed.

```
   <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
```

I think we can close the page using javascript function.

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the easiest way I've found to accomplish this.

Create a Visualforce Page (I have the same page named "CloseMe") with this Markup:

```
<apex:page >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.close();
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Then, redirect (by [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript) or Apex [PageReference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm)) to the page.

Also, **make sure all Profiles** have the necessary security to access the page.

Instead, you could try using an [ActionFunction](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) that calls the Apex Save action, then put the [`window.close();`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp) JavaScript on the OnComplete ActionFunction parameter, but I think that's unnecessarily complicated.